# C++ glfw unresolved external symbol errors

Tags: c++, opengl, linker-errors, glfw

I am trying to make a 3d game in C++ with glfw and opengl but I'm getting a lot of linker errors.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpLgp.png)

I've tried changing some linker settings but nothing I tried worked.

I'm using the example glfw code

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you passing to the linker on the command-line? Looks like you are not passing the library.

Comment: Find where your glfw `.lib` file is, copy the full path including the filename. Right click on your project, select properties, click on Linker, then on Input. Paste into Additional Dependencies.

Comment: I'm already doing that and when I look at the .cpp file it does not say anything is erroring  but when I try to build it outputs all those errors.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where the exact problem is without seeing your linker / compiler options, but these suggestions might solve your problem:

- If you are linking against a dll, you will need to define `GLFW_DLL` as a preprocessor macro
- Make sure that your linker can find glfw3.lib or glfw3dll.lib
- You have to link against glfw3dll.lib if you want to link against the dll

There is a [Guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html) on how to build apps with glfw on their website.